# Dependent WITH clauses in Oracle Reports

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, report

Why does Oracle's Report builder(connected to 11g DB) not allowing the following valid SQL?

```
with abc as 
(Select 1 as x from dual),
def as
(Select 2 as y from abc)
select x,y from abc,def
```

I am getting `ORA-00942: table or view does not exist (Select 2 as y from ==>abc)`
for the above.
When I execute the above SQL from SQL Developer connected to the same 11g database, it runs without any problems.
The following independent WITH clauses is accepted by the reports builder though,

```
with abc as 
(Select 1 as x from dual),
def as
(Select 2 as y from dual)
select x,y from abc,def
```

Is there a way to do this in reports builder or should I just have to cram the first WITH clause in the second one's FROM clause?. Thanks in advance.

PS:Report Builder version is 10.1.2.0.2

Comment: What version of Oracle Reports Builder are you writing your reports in?

Comment: @Ollie: Please see my revised question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a workaround for WITH clause problems posted on the Oracle forums here:
https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=710036

That you could implement to get around your problem.

Alternatively, could you not just use the current WITH queries within inline views in your query?

EDIT:
Like this (using your code).

```
SELECT x, y
  FROM 
       (SELECT 1 AS x
          FROM dual) abc,
       (SELECT 2 AS y
          FROM dual) def
```

Comment: I am not getting you. Could you please give an example for using it in inline views?

Comment: Nvm,I got it. Inline view -> using SELECT in the FROM clause of another SELECT. The reason that I didn't want to do this is, the actual query is huge and using it in FROM clause affects the readability very much.

Comment: @Digdug, I appreciate your want to have the readability improved in your queries but getting it working is the first step. Perhaps you could put the most complex query into the WITH clause and inline the less complex query? Not great but it would work.

Comment: ,you are right. I might just well use it as an inline view. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this same issue and this is how I overcame it:
Where you are using the inline alias, explicitly join it (inner, outer...) to another table. example:

```
with MyTabA as(
    select 1 theID, 'AA'
    thetext from dual
),
MytabB as(
    select 1 theID, '123 street Paul'
    theaddress from dual union select 2 theID, '123 street Paul'
    theaddress from dual union select 3 theID, '123 street Paul'
    theaddress from dual
)
Select MytabA.theid, mytaba.thetext, mytabb.theaddress
from MyTabA, MyTabB
Where MyTabA.theID = MyTabB.theid
;
```